# Sparse matrix library for Java

Tags: java, matrix

I am looking for a sparse matrix library in Java that can do multiplications on sparse integer matrices, where the matrices represent the adjacency relations of a graph. The requirement is roughly the following: the library should be able to load and multiply a few matrices of 10M×10M elements, containing approx. 5M non-zero elements each, when running on a commodity machine (~16 GBs of RAM). The [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) library for C++ satisfies this requirement. However, I couldn't find a good alternative for Java.

I looked at the following libraries:

- The [`SparseMatrix` class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/SparseMatrix.html) in the [Spark ML library](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html) only seems to support multiplication with a dense matrix.

  - Digging a bit deeper, the [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) library [used by Spark ML](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a5624c7ae29d6d49117dd78642879bf978212d30/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Matrices.scala#L25) states [the following](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Data-Structures#cscmatrix-sparse-matrix): "CSCMatrices are not fully supported yet. They are missing several basic operations."
  - It's also worth noting that [internally, Breeze uses](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/09241acb5ca491c4b68c9b91d9e27bb7a25cdfc2/math/build.sbt#L8) the [`netlib-java` library](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java).
- The [`OpenMapRealMatrix`](https://github.com/apache/commons-math/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4/linear/OpenMapRealMatrix.java) class of [Apache Commons Math](https://github.com/apache/commons-math) throws a `NumberIsTooLargeException`, as it only supports matrices with 2B elements (*"40,000,000,000 is larger than, or equal to, the maximum (2,147,483,647)"*)
- The [`SparseDoubleMatrix2D`](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/impl/SparseDoubleMatrix2D.html) class of the [Colt library](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/) throws a Java heap space error.
- The [`DMatrixSparseCSC`](http://ejml.org/javadoc/org/ejml/data/DMatrixSparseCSC.html) class of the [Efficient Java Matrix Library](http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) <strike>throws a `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException` when initializing a large matrix.</strike> This has been fixed since the question -- see the author's [comment](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51330/sparse-matrix-library-for-java?noredirect=1#comment73351_51330) and the accepted answer.
- The [`LinkedSparseMatrix`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.4/no/uib/cipr/matrix/sparse/LinkedSparseMatrix.html) class of [Matrix Toolkit Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_Toolkit_Java) is very quick to initialize, but does not handle multiplication well - multiplying an empty 1M×1M matrix takes ~6 minutes. [`CompDiagMatrix`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.3/no/uib/cipr/matrix/sparse/CompDiagMatrix.html) runs out of memory for a matrix of this size. Neither [`FlexCompColMatrix`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.3/no/uib/cipr/matrix/sparse/FlexCompColMatrix.html), nor [`FlexCompRowMatrix`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.3/no/uib/cipr/matrix/sparse/FlexCompRowMatrix.html) finish in 10 minutes. [`CompRowMatrix`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.4/no/uib/cipr/matrix/sparse/CompRowMatrix.html) and [`CompColMatrix`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.4/no/uib/cipr/matrix/sparse/CompColMatrix.html) have good performance for ~20k×20k matrices, but break down in performance for larger ones. (The Javadoc for the latest stable version, 1.0.4 does not advise which sparse matrix to use for static cases. A pull request [submitted more detailed documentation](https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java/pull/89/files) since, but 1.0.5-SNAPSHOT never made it to release and the project is now archived.)
- [Graphulo](http://graphulo.mit.edu/) is an implementation of [GraphBLAS](http://graphblas.org/), but is very complicated to use as it is designed to run on top of the [Apache Accumulo](https://accumulo.apache.org/) database.
- The [Universal Java Matrix Package](https://ujmp.org/) (UJMP) is a good fit on paper, but does not provide very good performance. Also, it seems abandoned and it is LGPL-licensed.
- Finally, various [JCuda](https://github.com/jcuda/) libraries could be useful, including [JCusparse](https://github.com/jcuda/jcusparse) and [JNvgraph](https://github.com/jcuda/jnvgraph), but all of these require a GPU.

I have also found a comprehensive survey at https://java-matrix.org/, created by the author of UJMP, which shows the state of the art in ~2015 and highlights that very few libraries support sparse matrices.

See also the [GitHub issue on the performance of sparse matrix multiplication in MTJ](https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java/issues/94).

A related question for a C/C++ library from 2010: [Looking for a C/C++ interface for efficient computation of huge sparse matrix in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413732/looking-for-a-c-c-interface-for-efficient-computation-of-huge-sparse-matrix-in/)

**Update (late 2019):** I've now researched this area for over a year and identified a few requirements that sparse matrix libraries need to meet in order to express graph algorithms and perform them efficiently:

1. support the definition of semirings other than the conventional plus-times arithmetic one (e.g. lor-land, min-plus)
2. support masking operations (only perform a given operation for elements selected by a mask)
3. allow multi-threaded execution

As of now, I could not find a Java library that satisfies *any* of the requirements above. Therefore, I have switched to C and use [SuiteSparse:GraphBLAS](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html).

**Update (Sep 2020):** EJML now satisfies requirement #1, see the [pull request introducing support for semirings](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml/pull/75).

**Update (Feb 2021):** [EJML v0.40](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml/releases/tag/v0.40) supports **all requirements**, offering some degree of concurrency and [masks](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml/pull/119).

Comment: I have no particular experience with Java, but if you Google "java lapack" you get a lot of hits such as http://www.netlib.org/blas/faq.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_Toolkit_Java and https://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/

Comment: Thanks! One challenge of this research is that most libraries optimize for medium-sized dense matrices - so even though EJML has [excellent performance according to some benchmarks](https://lessthanoptimal.github.io/Java-Matrix-Benchmark/manual/DescriptionRuntime/), it does not fit my reqs as my matrices are too big.

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/211/what-efficient-matrix-implementations-are-there-for-java?rq=1

Comment: No, I didn't - thanks. Unfortunately, MTJ does not seem to scale up to the millions. I extended my question with the results on MTJ.

Comment: There was a bug in EJML that has since been [fixed](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml/issues/40). As long as the number of non-zero elements does not exceed 2^31 you should be good. Sparse support is fairly new so issues are still being discovered.

Comment: Thanks, I clarified this in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two libraries I can recommend. Both support sparse matrices, including matrix-matrix multiplication, matrix-matrix element-wise multiplication and matrix-vector multiplication. Both are open-source, actively maintained, and available from the Maven Central.

1. [EJML](http://ejml.org/) (Efficient Java Matrix Library) is Apache-licensed (ASLv2) - [[source code]](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml), [[Maven]](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ejml). Recently (Sep 2020) it has been extended with support for [semirings](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml/pull/75).
2. [ojAlgo](http://ojalgo.org/) ("oj! Algorithms") is MIT-licensed - [[source code]](https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo), [[Maven]](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ojalgo/ojalgo).

For the sparse workloads I tested, EJML had far superior performance, so it's worth trying that one first.